# ¿Cómo hacer un diccionario de valores compartidos por dos diccionarios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Tengo dos diccionarios y me gustaria agrupar en una sola las claves que son compartidas por ambos así como los valores asociados en una tupla.

```
dic1 = {'burberry':2, 'chanel': 3, 'zara':2}
dic2 = {'burberry':1, 'chanel': 2, 'CorteIngless':5}
```

Sólo sé tomar las claves y valores de un diccionario cuyas claves también están en el otro. No sé cómo obtener los valores del otro.

```
{key:value_t for (key,value_t) in dic1.items() if key in dic2.keys()}
```

Me gustaria obtener:

```
{'burberry':(2,1), 'chanel': (3,2)}
```

Para hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT: Simple is better than complex

Sencillamente podemos obtener las claves repetidas haciendo una [intersección de conjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecci%C3%B3n_de_conjuntos). Luego, crear nuestro diccionario con una comprehensión de diccionarios:

```
dic1 = {'burberry':2, 'chanel': 3, 'zara':2}
dic2 = {'burberry':1, 'chanel': 2, 'CorteIngless':5}

repeated_keys = set(dic1) & set(dic2)
result = {key: (dic1[key], dic2[key]) for key in repeated_keys}
```

---

### Respuesta original

(*La dejo por acá porque igual considero que alguien puede beneficiarse de este otro approach, en el sentido que se muestra cómo usar grouby() y chain()*)

Puedes hacer uso de dos funciones superútiles del módulo `itertools`. Específicamente, [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) y [chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

En primer lugar, con `chain()` encadenamos los items de ambos diccionarios, y luego con `groupby()` los agrupamos de acuerdo a sus keys.

Finalmente, nos aseguramos que el diccionario resultante (`result`) incluya las keys que se encuentren incluidas en ambos diccionarios `dic1` y `dic2`.

Lo positivo de usar estas funciones, es que ambas devuelven iteradores que no son evaluados, salvo cuando se necesitan.

Lo único que hay que tener cuidado al usar `groupby` es que para obtener el resultado que queremos, el iterable que toma como argumento debe estar ordenado de acuerdo a la misma `key` que recibe la función `groupby` como tal.

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain


KEY = 0

dic1 = {'burberry':2, 'chanel': 3, 'zara':2}
dic2 = {'burberry':1, 'chanel': 2, 'CorteIngless':5}

dictionary_key_callback = lambda dictionary_item: dictionary_item[KEY]

dictionaries_items = chain(dic1.items(), dic2.items())
sorted_dictionaries_items = sorted(dictionaries_items,
                                   key=dictionary_key_callback)
grouped_dictionaries = groupby(sorted_dictionaries_items,
                               key=dictionary_key_callback)

result = {
    dict_key: tuple(value for _, value in group)
    for dict_key, group in grouped_dictionaries
    if dict_key in dic1 and dict_key in dic2
}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```py
{'burberry': (2, 1), 'chanel': (3, 2)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Una solución general para cualquier número de diccionarios podría consistir en agrupar todos esos diccionarios en uno solo, haciendo que los valores sean listas:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

# Una lista con los diccionarios a procesar
diccionarios = [dic1, dic2]

# Ahora creamos el diccionario unificado
for dic in diccionarios:
  for k, v in dic.items():
    result[k].append(v)
```

Aplicando esto sobre los diccionarios de ejemplo que das, el resultado sería:

```
{'CorteIngless': [5], 'burberry': [2, 1], 'chanel': [3, 2], 'zara': [2]}
```

Ahora podrías quedarte sólo con los ítems del diccionario cuyo valor tenga más de un elemento (y ya de paso convierto esas listas en tuplas para que la salida sea tal como la que pones en la pregunta):

```
result = { k: tuple(v) for k,v in result.items() if len(v)>1}
```

Y el resultado es `{'burberry': (2, 1), 'chanel': (3, 2)}`

Answer (score 2):

Por añadir otra solución más a las dos magníficas respuestas, lo puedes quedar todo en una linea con Dictionary Comprehension:

```
{k:(dic1[k], dic2[k]) for k in dic1 if k in dic2}
```

**Salida:**

```
{'burberry': (2, 1), 'chanel': (3, 2)}
```

1. `for k in dic1`: Iteramos sobre las claves del diccionario primero
2. `if k in dic2`: chequeamos si la clave se encuentra en el diccionario segundo.
3. `k:(dic1[k], dic2[k])`: en el caso de que se encuentre creamos la `clave:valor`.